# "test.exe encountered a breakpoint"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I am writing a UNIX `paste` clone. However I keep getting "encountered a breakpoint" messages, but VS won't tell me on what line it happened.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INITALLOC   16
#define STEP         8

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (horzmerge(argc - 1, argv + 1) == 0) {
        perror("horzmerge");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    getchar();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
int horzmerge(int nfiles, const char **filenames)
{
    FILE **files;
    char *line;
    int i;

    if ((files = malloc(nfiles * sizeof (FILE *))) == NULL)
        return 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nfiles; ++i)
        if ((files[i] = fopen(filenames[i], "r")) == NULL)
            return 0;

    do {
        for (i = 0; i < nfiles; ++i) {
            if (getline(files[i], &line) == 0)
                return 0;
            fprintf(stdout, "%s", line);
            free(line);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    } while (!feof(files[0]));  /* we can still get another line */

    for (i = 0; i < nfiles; ++i)
        fclose(files[i]);
    free(files);
    return 1;
}
int getline(FILE *fp, char **dynline)
{
    size_t nalloced = INITALLOC;
    int c, i;

    if ((*dynline = calloc(INITALLOC, sizeof(char))) == NULL)
        return 0;

    for (i = 0; (c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        if (i == nalloced)
            if ((*dynline = realloc(*dynline, nalloced += STEP)) == NULL)
                return 0;
        (*dynline)[i] = c;
    }
    (*dynline)[i] = '\0';
    if (c == EOF)
        return EOF;
    return i;
}
```

I placed breakpoints, and saw that it was the `free(line)` statement in `horzmerge`. But sometimes the program runs fine. Sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes I get a "Heap corrupted" in `getline`. I've been working on this code for a week, still can't find the bug(s).

Comment: Try using something like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)?

Comment: No function prototypes? And what about `while (!feof(files[0]))`

Comment: @WeatherVane using the `feof` call, I can tell if I need to read more lines or not.

Comment: Have you read the man page for `feof()`? And anyway, that's only the first file in the array.

Comment: It is bad because the loop will be executed once more than intended, since it tells whether EOF was reached **after** an attempt to read? @WeatherVane

Comment: It does not tell you that end of file was reached. It tells you made a duff read.

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the line where you null-terminate the input string is capable of overrunning the buffer you `calloc`ed or `realloc`ed. That has the potential of corrupting your heap when you `free` that buffer.

Dont't forget to leave room for the null character at the end of the string when you allocate memory.

Null-terminated strings are like disco. They still suck forty years later.